# Multi columns bar chart by separating one columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have one dataframe same here.

```
type    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6
A       0   20  14  4   100 0
B       10  30  23  9   12  0
C       20  10  0   20  24  34
```

I want plot bar graph same image.
matplotlib python

[image]

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I transformed the format of the data, using 'type' as the index, and outputting it in a one-row, three-column format with a plot of 'pandas'.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import io

data = '''
type c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6
A 0 20 14 4 100 0
B 10 30 23 9 12 0
C 20 10 0 20 24 34
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+', index_col=0)
df = df.T
df.plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, layout=(1,3))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just need to `show()` to keep each plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = """type    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6
A       0   20  14  4   100 0
B       10  30  23  9   12  0
C       20  10  0   20  24  34"""
a = [[t for t in l.split(" ") if t!=""] for l in data.split("\n")]

df = pd.DataFrame(a[1:], columns=a[0])
df = df.astype({c:"int64" for c in df.columns if "c" in c})


for i, r in df.iterrows():
    df.iloc[i, 1:].T.plot.bar(title=df.loc[i, "type"])   
    plt.show()
```